# Karma Require.js -- changing directory structure is killing everything

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, karma-runner

I've been trying to set up karma to work with Require.js now for a few days (and then later use require with angular) and it's been amazingly frustrating. Here's what my file tree looks like for this example:

```
$ tree
.
|-- public
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- src
|       |-- app.js
|       `-- main.js
|-- config
|   |-- karma.conf.js  
|-- lib
|   |-- jquery.js
|   |-- require.js
|   `-- underscore.js
|-- src
|   |-- app.js
|   `-- main.js
`-- test
    |-- appSpec.js
    `-- test-main.js
```

### note:

This repository I'm working on is a clone of the one used in the [karma requirejs example](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html) . The ONLY difference between the [karma example githubs' code](https://github.com/kjbekkelund/karma-requirejs) and my code are the 3 changes to the file directory structure:

1. /karma.conf.js

   ```
       ==> /config/karma.conf.js
   ```
2. /src/

   ```
       ==> /public/src/
   ```
3. /index.html

   ```
       ==> /public/index.html
   ```

So. Right now in order to get everything working, it would make sense that you would have to:

1. run karma from within the conf directory,
2. in the karma.conf.js file change:

   ```
   basePath: '',
   ```

   to

   ```
   basePath: '../',
   ```
3. and in the test/test-main.js (which is the requirejs.config file) change:

requirejs.config({

```
// Karma serves files from '/base' 
baseUrl: '/base/src',
```

to

```
requirejs.config({
    // Karma serves files from '/base'
    baseUrl: '../base/src',
```

but it appears that no matter what I do I continue to get the same error:

```
ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/src/app.js!'
Uncaught Error: Script error for: app
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at /node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
```

or

```
    Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at /node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141

    Uncaught Error: Script error for: underscore
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at /node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
```

---

## ^tldr: [check the repo](https://github.com/andrew-luhring/karma-require-whathaveyoudone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to add

```
paths: {
   'jquery': '../lib/jquery',
   'underscore': '../lib/underscore'
   'app' : '../public/src/app'     <====

  },
```

whereas in the original example code app.js is being added via:

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
        tests.push(file);
    }
}
```

so it would be redundent to add it to the paths.

```
paths: {
    'jquery': '../lib/jquery',
    'underscore': '../lib/underscore',
},
```